# Wrong zorder in viewport but ok in cycles render

Tags: 3d-view

I have stumbled upon a problem while using [Images as planes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html) addon. When loop cutting and bending the plane, the object is wrongly sorted in viewport, while correctly rendered in cycles. The material is simple texture to emissive. The image is PNG, but does it matter with emissive material? Normals seem to be correct (cyan lines on the image). The problem is not present when using "Solid" viewport shading.

[image]

Thank you for all suggestions.

Comment: Does the image have transparency? Import images as planes will make an Alpha Blend material for those, so you'll have the usual alpha sorting problems.

Comment: Alpha blend material? But I'm using emissive shader. Is there any other material setting?

Comment: Is that what it is? Turn off Alpha when you use Import Image as Plane, or switch the blend mode to Opaque afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scurest was right! All that was needed was to set blend mode in material properties:
`Material properties -> Viewport display -> Settings -> Blend mode = opaque`

[image: Material properties -> Viewport display -> Settings -> Blend mode = opaque]